# Rails linked tables belongs_to or has_many not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html-table, belongs-to

I have three tables User, User_types and Purchases.

- **user:**  id  etc
- **user_purchase_types**: id, typename, user_id
- **purchases:** id, user_id, user_purchase_type_id, note

Users can have any number of purchases and user_types. A purchase can have one user_purchase_type.

Users can log in, create types, do purchases etc - this all works fine

However I want, when listing purchases, to see the user_purchase_types.typename, rather than the id number. Simple I think, use belongs_to, they already have the right id fields, should just work. But it doesn't

I have tried a million variations of belongs_to, has_many , has_many through etc etc but cannot get the right relationship and so show the typename rather than the id.

There are the right foreign_key id fields in the tables so this should work.

When listing the purchases in the purchase controller I use @purchase = current_user.purchases. 
When looping this to display in the view I think I should be able to use purchase.user_purchase_type.typename but this gives me a 'NoMethodError'.

What am I doing wrong or should I just denormalise the DB and have done with it?

EDIT Models as req

```
class UserPurchaseType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :purchase
  attr_accessible :typename, :id
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :purchases, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :user_purchase_types, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_purchase_types
  attr_accessible :date, :user_purchase_type_id, :note 
end
```

index.erb file

```
<% @purchases.each do |purchase| %>    #this works
  <tr>  
   <td><%= purchase.user_purchase_type.typename %></td>  #this fails
    <td><%= purchase.date %></td>
    <td><%= purchase.note %></td>
   </tr><p>
<% end %>
```

purchase controller

```
def index
  @user_purchase_types = current_user.user_purchase_types           # this works
  @purchases = current_user.purchases              #this works
```

Comment: can you show user_type,purchase ,and user model

Comment: You misspelled purchase in the view "purhcase.user_type.typename", but I suppose that is not your problem right?

Comment: class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :purchases, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :user_purchase_types, :dependent => :destroy

private

endclass UserType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :typename, :id
end

Comment: no @Henrik spelling sadly not the problem

Comment: Take a look on your controller, on the strong parameters on the bottom..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add foreign key in your existing association.

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_purchase_types, :foreign_key => 'user_purchase_type_id'
  attr_accessible :date, :user_purchase_type_id, :note 
end
```

Comment: This plus adding belongs_to :user_purchase_type did it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is a one to one relationship between them rgt?
yes you should be able to be able to access typename, but by using @purchase.user_type.typename. and not purchase.user_type.typename.

and would be better if you could show user models too.

and is current_user defined?

also you can try by finding out the usertype first and then access it:
@user_type = UserType.find(@purchase.user_type_id)
@user_type.typename

You should always try the relationships first on console and see if your getting it rgt

---

Your relationships are all messed up.
You have a one to many relationships between purchases and user purchase type.
and therefore you can not use @purchase.user_purchase_type.typename
You have to use

```
 @purchase.user_purchase_types.each do |i|
i.typename
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :user_purchase_types
   attr_accessible :date, :user_purchase_type_id, :note 
end
```

The `Purchase` -> `UserPurchaseType` association is a `has_many` relationship but you seem to be trying to use it with `user_purchase_type_id` which would indicate a `belongs_to :user_purchase_type` relationship, but your association is `has_many :user_purchase_types`

It sounds like you may want something like:

```
<% @purchases.each do |purchase| %>    #this works
  <tr>  
   <td><%= purchase.user_purchase_types.collect(&:typename).join(',') %></td>
    <td><%= purchase.date %></td>
    <td><%= purchase.note %></td>
   </tr><p>
<% end %>
```

to list all your `UserPurchaseType` `typename`'s, comma separated.

If you do this, make sure when you load your `@purchases` in the controller to also include a `.includes(:user_purchase_types)`. This will eager load the association and avoid rails loading each `UserPurchaseType` as you iterate through.